# The java -p option, what does it do and where is it documented?

Tags: java

The java command has a -p option but I can't find any documentation for it.

**What does the `-p` option of the java command do, and where can I find it documented?**

I've searched for it https://www.google.com/search?q=java+-p+option&oq=java+-p+option but don't see it explained.  The top link is an IBM link

- https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ztpf/2020?topic=applications-specifying-java-options-system-properties - and when searching on that page for -p no matches are found.

Several other links explored as well

- https://opensource.com/article/22/4/jvm-parameters-java-developers
- https://geekflare.com/important-jvm-options/
- https://www.jrebel.com/sites/rebel/files/pdfs/cheat-sheet-rebel-jvm-options.pdf

Comment: If you type `java` in the command line, the usage options are printed, which include the `-p` flag and that it's an alias for `--module-path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is:

- The `-p` option is an abbreviation for the `--module-path` option.
- The `-p` (or `--module-path`) option was introduced in JDK 9 so earlier versions of Java will not include the option or the concept of **Java modules**.

The JDK documentation for the `-p` option was first made available in Java 9:

- Java 9 - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/tools-and-command-reference.htm

Subsequent versions of Java include the `--module-path` (or `-p`) option.

The text says:

> --module-path modulepath... or -p modulepath
> A semicolon (;) separated list of directories in which each directory is a directory of modules.  
> *[My Note] In unix the list is colon (:) separated.*

An introduction to **Java Modules** can be found at:

- https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html
- YouTube JavaOne presentation **Modules in One Lesson** by Mark Reinhold. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGX-JfMl9-Y
- Book - https://www.manning.com/books/the-java-module-system

Answer (score 3):

This option and all other available options should be listed and explained on the official documentation of the `java` tool:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/java.html

You can find all Java Tools explained at:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/index.html

These are just for the Java 21 version, for other versions, and much more information, start at:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/index.html